# getting html file from directory in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have around 5 files which are in html and I was trying to generate a cod for getting them one by one in my python environment without copying them in my ipython environment. Here is the code I tried:

```
import os
path = 'D:\\pdftohtml'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    tree = ET.parse("calculation.xml")
```

but this code is not giving me the desired output.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please be more specific in what you're trying to achieve. What does "generate a cod" mean? You're not utilising the `fullname` variable within your code. If you do, particularly as an argument supplied to `ET.parse(..)`, does that solve your issue?

Comment: Use `glob`. Way more easy. `glob.glob('D:\\pdftohtml\\*.html')` will return an array with all *.html files in that particular directory. It returns complete path and you don't have to use any join.

Comment: import glob
import os
from lxml import etree
for file in glob.glob('D:\\pdftohtml\\*.html'):
    with open(file) as f:
        data = etree.parse(f)

Comment: I used this code

Comment: @GeetanjaliBisht : So your issue is solved now ?

Comment: no....its still not solved

Comment: i want a code which can read all the xml files from my computer to python environment